# Is there a way to set combat behavior?

Tags: planescape-torment

Is there a way to set combat behavior in Planescape Torment: Enhanced Edition like you can in the Baldur's Gate series?

In Baldur's Gate you can pick a particular AI strategy for your companions to reduce micromanaging them, and I was curious if a similar option existed in Planescape that I'm currently overlooking.